# Verifying botkit against the slack events api

Tags: slack, slack-api, botkit

I'm having a pretty basic problem - trying to upgrade my botkit app from 0.7.x -> 4.x.
I've used `yo botkit` to generate a new v4 bot, according to [these instructions](https://botkit.ai/getstarted.html). Now that I try to configure the bot with slack I can't verify the events api the same way I did with the v0.7 bot.

When I go to [slacks events api url](https://api.slack.com/apps/%3Capp-id%3E/event-subscriptions?) and try to verify a request url, my node app is responding with a `404 not found` error.
Looking at the code, it seems that the endpoint for `/slack/receive` which slack is trying to access is indeed removed from the code.
This prevents my bot from listening to messages and responding to them.

When I was configuring the bot in v0.7.x, I just cloned [this repo](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-slack) and followed [these instructions](https://botkit.ai/docs/provisioning/slack-events-api.html), but when I try to follow these instructions with the starter provided for v4.x the guide fails and I can't find a more relevant one.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: you might want to ask this question to the maintainer of the repo: https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-slack/issues

Comment: That repo is deprecated, but I have opened an issue in the main repository which is actively maintained, thanks to your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url has changed in v4 - it is now /api/messages

Comment: Thanks! I was really bouncing off the walls trying to figure this out.